# Adding a loading image when image is processed

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading, captcha

I have here an ajax function that reloads captcha images..

```
$('#reload_captcha').click(function(event){
  $('#captcha_image').attr('src', $('#captcha_image').attr('src')+'#');
});
```

Its working but, is there a way to add a loading image while the image is reloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `.ajaxstart()` for this. Here is detailed explanation for it:
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: I don't understand how to work on it.. can you help me with this draconis?